What movie is about a mother with an addicted son going back to her dysfunctional family for a wedding?
A mother with her addicted son goes back to her completely dysfunctional family for a wedding. She also has a daughter (who is cutting or anorexic I don't remember) who does not want to come because she doesn't want to face her father. In the end, she decides to come, finally faces him, decides she doesn't want anything to do with him and stops waiting for his attention. 
I remember all through the film, the entire family keeps on calling those 3 crazy when in reality, they are the sanest of all. There's a scene where the son has to wear lipstick to hide he's been using, one with the granpa on a landmower or a tractor gone wild. I also think the mother was abused by her ex-husband and that the entire family is in denial and blames her for the divorce. 
Thanks for telling me the name of the film if you know it : it's driving me crazy ! :)

Thank you for the detailed plot description. Pretty sure I know what you're after, but some basic details (like approximate year, country\language, genre and possible actors) can always help.

It's Another Happy Day from 2011 with Ellen Barkin, Kate Bosworth, Demi Moore and many others.

A wedding at her parents' Annapolis estate hurls high-strung Lynn into the center of touchy family dynamics.

Her son is a drug addict who wears lipstick, her daughter cuts herself, her father has dementia and rides around on a lawnmower and she has an abusive ex. Here's the trailer:




YEEEEEEEEEEEES, that's the one !!!! Thank you so much !
